# Keyboard dismissing on redux store change on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, keyboard

Whenever a part of my redux state that I am subscribed to updates, my TextInput loses focus and the keyboard dismisses. The problem used to be much worse when I was destructuring part of state coming back from `useSelector`. Switching to a selector for each specific value I need greatly alleviated this problem (and I'm sure helped my overall performance), but did not solve it.

I am using the useSelector and useDispatch hooks throughout the whole app without dedicated HOCs.
These are the relevant packages that I am using

```
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0"
```

I am aiming that this will work like the `useState` hook, the component will re-render but not dismiss my keyboard.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my keyboard in a textinnput. I also used redux, useSelector and useDispatch so I tought it might have something todo with it. But it didn't..

The textInput was located inside a component which i mapped from an array.

```
<View key={index + '' + new Date().getMilliseconds()} style={styles.container} >
  <View style={styles.goalcontainer}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => copyGoalValues(index)}>
      <Text style={styles.goaltext}>
        {goalhh} x {goalkg}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

What bugged it was that I gave the component a key that was random (new Date().getMilliseconds()) so every time the application rendered it got a new key which made the component believe it was a new component and therefore closed the keyboard.